# How to run monitor-dashboard in Cloud9?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I install monitor-dashboard ( https://github.com/lorenwest/monitor-dashboard ) by npm in my Cloud9's workspace and followed the steps to configure by external mode.

When I run the process, there are no errors, but in the URL with the port that says where I can find the dashboard, that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like monitor-dashboard runs on 4200 by default and doesn't give an easy way to change that port. Cloud9 exposes ports 8080, 8081, and 8082 so replace [these occurrences of 4200](https://github.com/lorenwest/monitor-dashboard/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=4200) with 8081, run it again, then go to https://yourworkspace-preview.url:8081 and you should be good.

Comment: I changed the port 4200 to 8081 in the occurrences but still didn't worked fine, any other suggestions?